# How to make Plex show song titles?

Tags: plex

I purchased quite many songs on iTunes and after I got a NAS and played with Plex, I added some songs to the Music library.

But Plex doesn't show the song's title, even though the meta data should have it, and even, the file name itself is the title.  Is there a way to make Plex show the song's title?

Comment: You don't see the title when playing the music or when listing the files? For reference, this is what I see for a music file: https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSSGw.png and https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4Zcj.png

Comment: when playing the music...  how do you "list the files"?  you mean inside of Plex? I guess when playing the music it won't show the name, so when listing the files inside Plex it won't show it either. It is taking "Untitled" to be the title. When in the list of songs, I only saw the singer's name, not title

Comment: On the top left where the songs are listed, change Artists or Albums to Tracks (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/7CrTP.png). The title should be seen.